# how to return value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return my `respone`.  I called like that I am getting First alert as  `undefined` (it mean it is not returning) and second alert `true`.

```
 alert(checkDeviceDataNetwork());
 function checkDeviceDataNetwork(){
   var networkResponse;
   bridge_g.callHandler('NetworkReachable',"" , function(response) {
               alert(response);
               networkResponse=response; 
               return networkResponse;
               if(response=="false"){
                    alert("Please check the network");
               }});
 }
```

Comment: Please, make your code readable. Take care of indents

Comment: how it will execute statement after `return` statement? `return networkResponse;  if(response=="false"){ alert("Please check the network");  }`

Comment: Actually There is comunnication between IOS cod and javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a callback into the function

```
 checkDeviceDataNetwork(function(err, message) {
   // bubble error if present; check console for this one
   if (err) throw err;

   // otherwise alert message
   alert(message);
 });

 function checkDeviceDataNetwork(callback){
   var networkResponse;
   bridge_g.callHandler('NetworkReachable',"" , function(response) {
               callback(null, response);
               networkResponse=response; 
               if(response=="false"){
                    callback(Error("Please check the network"));
               }
               return networkResponse;
       });
 }
```